# Tinymce: can't edit content after effect

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tinymce

I'm useing jQuery to slide in the TinyMCE editor, the code is not executed until the animation is finished, however when I want to type within the editor I can't, below are the script's I used:

when the page is loaded

```
    $("#PageEditor").hide();
    editor_id = $("#PageEditor textarea").attr('id');
    tinymce.get(editor_id).hide();
```

when editor button is clicked:

```
$("#homeContainer").hide('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 500, function(){
    $("#PageEditor").show('drop', {direction: 'up'}, 500);
    editor_id = $("#PageEditor textarea").attr('id');
    LoadTinyMCE();
    tinymce.get(editor_id).show();
});
```

the function LoadTinyMCE:

```
        tinymce.init({
            theme : 'modern',
            selector: "#Editor",
            plugins: [
                "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
                "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
                "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
            ],
            toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image"
        });
```

when I don't use the effect I don't have a problem with using it, it only does this once I use an effect to call it, i've tried searching but I cannot get the same result.

extra info:
I use latest jQuery + jQueryUI and TinyMCE 4.0.12